# Google Places API can't found results

Tags: android, google-places-api

Autocomplete feature about places stopped working in my android app.
I have the below code

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    .setCountry("GR")
                    .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
                    .build();

Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .setFilter(typeFilter)
                            .build(activity);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1009);

    Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
               switch (requestCode) {
                    case 1009:
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                            //Do something with Place
                        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                            Log.i("address status", status.getStatusMessage());
                        }
                        break;
```

But in any 'valid' input I pass it never returns a result. Always get "can't found result". The same code it worked perfect before. Any ideas?

I use: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'`

Comment: Mine is working now. They really should have something like this (https://status.cloud.google.com/) for all their APIs where there is a place you can report possible downtimes as well as review current status.

Comment: Yeah! And mine also working now...weird
Maybe you have right @napkinsterror

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by regenerating the key.