# Google Places AutoComplete on iOS - Can't Load Search Results - Try Again

Tags: ios, google-api, google-places-api, google-api-client

I am posting this here because I don't know where else to post this. Today, our application is no longer returning results for Google Places API. We are seeing the request go through on the Google Developers Console, but all phones are returning no results.

This number is climbing for today and each one of these users are stuck in the login / onboarding flow of my app.

[image]

Update (Closer Image for the last hour):[image]

Here is an example flow of what I am seeing on all iPhones we are testing and receiving the same from our users.

They search for their location. They might or might not see some autocomplete options:

[image]

After selecting one or waiting they will see this

[image]

This is what happens

[image]

Any and all help is appreciated. Any hints on who to contact or what I should do is important.

Does google have a services page or are other apps experiencing this issue? If so, which apps?

Related SO Questions posted recently:

- Android: [Google Places API can't found results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163797/google-places-api-cant-found-results)
- iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163583/google-autocomplete-wont-load-suggestions-and-instead-shows-cant-load-search

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am facing same issue. Suddenly everything stopped

Comment: @Shah, I didn't find a real solution. This was really bad for a 48 period and every once in awhile happens for a couple minutes, but has stopped happening for long periods. I imagine this is on Google end as long as you are seeing it sometimes. You just have to wait. Also, updating to paid version of Google Maps might help but that is just a guess of mine.

Comment: @napkinsterror did u find any solution , m still facing this issue , is their any alternate of places api?

Answer (score 9):

Easily to fix it.

1. Go to your https://console.developers.google.com/apis/
2. Choose "Library" - "Google Places API for iOS"
3. ENABLE (Blue Button)

API Key as same as Google Maps APIKey

Comment: i have enabled places api and the key is as same as maps api key still facing the same issue, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Same I have enabled Places API Key. But still it is showing me same error "Try Again". do you have alternate solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: @veerendrapratapsingh Please check again the Blue Button that you enable is for Google Places API or Google Maps API. I have been confused about this because the UI of Google is terrible.

Answer (score 3):

This was the same issue to me.

According to new rules by Google we have to compulsory setup a [Billing Account](https://console.developers.google.com/billing).

Maybe you have something left with the payment setup.
Check the status for your Billing account, it might be closed.
Complete the pending stuff and this won't an issue anymore.
Hope that helps you!

Comment: Sagar Wankhede Do google auto debit from our card if we exceed the limit.? please confirm.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to look out for.

First, go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ and make sure the Google Places API is enabled. Select your project on the top left, then select library on the left as well. Then, look for "Places API" and enable the API.

[image]

Second, make sure you have a billing account enabled. To do so, go to https://console.developers.google.com/billing/ and proceed to create an account. Make sure your project is linked to this account as well. To link the account, go to your project and select the "Billing" option from the hamburger menu on the top left corner.

[image]

[image]

Lastly, if you have application restrictions, make sure the bundle identifier from your iOS project is associated with the API key you're using. Go to your project in XCode, click on the General tab, and copy the value by "Bundle Identifier". Then, go back to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ and make sure your project is selected. Then, go to the "Credentials" tab on the left. Select your key, and go down to where it says **Accept requests from an iOS application with one of these bundle identifiers**
and paste the value in the text box below.

If you have API restrictions, make sure the Places API is added to your list of accessible APIs.

Click "Regenerate Key" at the top and use the new key generated under where it says "API Key" in your project. This process may take up to 5 minutes to take into effect.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might have hit your 1k/day API request limit. To increase it to 150k/day, you just need to verify your credit card. https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/usage?hl=en_US

Comment: Do google auto debit from our card if we exceed the limit.? please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Go to your https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

**Step 2**

Select you project and go to library setting. Sear Google Places and click on Google Places box. Click on Enable button.

[image]

Comment: I already enabled api keys but it is still show "Try Again" result. have you any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue come in my project also. and I try all solutions but they are not working for me.

Then I **update my pod** and then my google API is starting working.

So, please try to **update a pod**.